# Как поменять цвет подсказок в eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, opensource

В один момент при наведение мышкой на название класса или метода вплывающая справка стала с черным фоном и черными буквами, как поменять фон этих всплывающих элементов? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Window → Preferences → General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Basic → {Information background color} and/or {Information text color}